# Notice: array to string conversion in line 23

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include 'db.inc.php';


//function that well return search results
//takes the keywords entered by user

function search_results ($keywords){

    //code here
    $returned_results= array();//array that will contain results
    $where= ""; // constract of query for results

    $keywords = preg_split ('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
         //function split values by space
     // (hello aya) is like ( hello  aya )

    $total_keywords = count($keywords);
         //count number of words entered ex(ayoy adel =2 , a b c s = 4)


    foreach ($keywords as $key=>$keyword){
    $where .="`keywords` LIKE '%$keywords%'";
               if ($key != ($total_keywords -1 )){
                 $where .= " AND " ;
               }

        }

       $results = "SELECT `title` , `subject` , `id` FROM `` WHERE $where ; ";
       }

    //array begins from 0 , this erro

    //$key=>$keyword key=0 , 1, 2   $keyword value in database
    //
    //
    //

    /*$sqlQuery= " SELECT `keywords` FROM `question` WHERE `keywords` LIKE `%hci%` AND  `keywords` LIKE `%what%` ";
*/

?>
```

Comment: `$where .="``keywords`` LIKE '%$keyword%'";` `$keywords` is your array; `$keyword` is the individual keyword from the foreach loop

Comment: You got this script, from video tutorial of phpacadmy, I would advice you to change your connection source to PDO, as it is not secure

Comment: yeah that's right
Iam still a beginner in php and mysql 
what do youm mean by PDO ? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line here:

```
$where .="`keywords` LIKE '%$keywords%'";
```

includes the `$keywords` variable which is an array, not a string. You probably meant to use the `$keyword` variable there.

Comment: thanks alot pilsetnieks  , it helped  
that was my mistake ^ ^